# JFace LabelProvider: How can I know the header/name of a column within a LabelProvider?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-plugin

this is the normal way for defining what to write in a Column using LabelProvider

```
@Override
public String getColumnText(final Object element, final int iColumn) {
            switch (iColumn) {
            case 0:
..
            case 1:
..
            default:
...
            }
}// getColumText()
```

which means I am given the id of the column.
How can I get teh "header" of the column given the id within the LabelProvider?
something like

```
String str = xxx.getColumnName( iColumn );
```

I don't find it.

Comment: Using a separate `ColumnLabelProvider` for each column is more usual these days for multiple columns. But neither of these provides a way to get the column name. Why do you need it?

Comment: Hi greg, thanks.
Do you have a link to any example with different ColumnLabelProvider? It would make sense (the "case" thing is inefficient and against encapsulation), but I dont understand how multiple label providers'd be managed. I suspect that would solve my problem.
I need it because I cannot directly use the index -the columns are registered externally and asynchronously and therefore who will manage the content doesn't know in what position (index) the column is. I did found critics about the use of Column indexes -as an old fashioned way of managing items- so there must be alternatives

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of using `ColumnLabelProvider`. This uses the `TableColumnLayout` which is set on a `Composite` which just contains the `TableViewer`, this allows the layout to adjust column sizes if the control is resized.

```
final Composite tableComp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

tableComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

final TableColumnLayout layout = new TableColumnLayout();

tableComp.setLayout(layout);

TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(tableComp, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

Table table = viewer.getTable();

col = new TableViewerColumn(_viewer, SWT.LEAD);
col.setLabelProvider(new NameColumnLabelProvider());
col.getColumn().setText(Messages.title_filename);
layout.setColumnData(col.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(70));

col = new TableViewerColumn(_viewer, SWT.TRAIL);
col.setLabelProvider(new DurationColumnLabelProvider());
col.getColumn().setText(Messages.title_duration);
layout.setColumnData(col.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(30));


private static class NameColumnLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider
{
  @Override
  public String getText(final Object element)
  {
    // return name column label
  }
}


private static class DurationColumnLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider
{
  @Override
  public String getText(final Object element)
  {
    // return duration column label
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this has to do with the problem I had, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, funny I never read your answer greg :( thanks a lot anyways :)
However, what you propose requires you know before hand what are the columns. What I did creates columns dinamically which are added to the treeview.

What I finally did:
-Externally manage a map of id/label

Goods:
-Simple: Independent of Eclipse/JFace, easy to understand, portable.
Bads:
- Well, whenever I dinamicall y add a column, I have to add it in the map, and same with removing. But once done, it is clear (other methods which my add columns in the future (no need in principle because I didn it general), must consider to register them within the map.

-It would have been nice that it were encapsulated within JFace.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
make ur own labelprovider with private attribute "TableViewer referencedTableViewer".
build constructor using this attribute.

now u can reference to tableviewer in getColumnText-method:

```
    @Override
public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex) {

    String columnTitle = referencedTableViewer.getTable()
                                              .getColumn(columnIndex).getText();
...
```

Step 2:
build TableViewer, instantiate labelprovider with reference to TableViewer